# How to send instructions to a pySpark shell?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am wondering if there is some way to send instructions to a running pyspark shell in Linux from an external application.

For example, imagine we have some functions that make transformations or actions to `DataFrames` but I don't want to run them in the normal way (by running a script or with a Notebook). I would like to set up something in order to have a listener terminal so I could provide instructions and the spark shell interprets and run the requests.

Comment: I am curious, why bother? We have great projects like Livy out there...